# How do I fit a bivariate normal distribution to a data set using R?

Tags: r, estimation, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a 2D data set, and I do not know its distribution.

I have used R to calculate mean and covariance.

How can I fit a bivariate normal distribution to my data set?

Comment: If you mean a general bivariate normal distribution it is not well defined without specifying a covariance.

Comment: That is the bivariate normal distribution then. You have simply used method of moments estimators.